# How do I get the value of the text input inside a <td> element (Without JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I get the value of the text input inside a  element?

I have multiple ids so I assigned their strings first into an array;

```
var itemArray = ["regpay", "overtime","absent","nightdiff","ctpa","salary","hdmf","otallowance","others"];
```

and I instantiated them using a for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++)
{
    var e = $("<td><input type=\"text\" autocomplete=\"off\" name=\""+itemArray[i]+"\" id=\""+itemArray[i]+"\"/></td>");
    var mytest =e.find('#'+itemArray[i]).val();
    alert(mytest);
}
```

the error says "$ is not defined";
How can I get the value of the textboxes inside a td element

?

I've also tried using:

```
try
{
    var Row = document.getElementById(itemArray[i]);
    var Cell = Row.getElementsByTagName("td");
    var val = Cell.getElementById(itemArray[i]);
}
```

but the val variable doesn't return anything so I assumed that td doesn't explicitly take the value of the textbox inside it.

Comment: If you're not using jQuery, why would you expect `$` to be defined? That's a shortcut for `jQuery` (when the library is included).

Comment: Yes, I kinda realized that just now. However, I am not using JQuery and I wanted to get the value inside the element without using one.

Comment: You...want to know how to retrieve the text from a given `<td>` element? Or you want to assign a given text *to* the `<td>` element? What you're asking, especially "without jQuery," makes no sense since you're apparently trying to use jQuery. What is it that you want help with?

Comment: Yes, I apologize for the title. The first time I tried $ is that I didn't know it was a JQuery function. I just want to get the value of a textbox inside a td element in javascript.

Comment: This sounds like you have existing HTML, from which you want to retrieve values? If you could post your ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) HTML that would help us to help you. And don't worry about not wanting jQuery answers, but you might want to clarify your question and remove the (attempted) jQuery from it, while you're adding your relevant HTML.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you for the help sir. I have already solved my problem using royhowie 's answer. Thank you for the answer again, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a list of `#ids`, then all you have to do is use the [`document.getElementById` query selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById):

```js
var ids = [ "regpay", "overtime","absent", "nightdiff", "ctpa", "salary",
            "hdmf", "otallowance", "others"];
var r = [];

ids.forEach(function (id) {
  r.push(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML);
})

alert("text found:" + r);
```

```html
<p id='regpay'>0</p>
<p id='overtime'>1</p>
<p id='absent'>2</p>
<p id='nightdiff'>3</p>
<p id='ctpa'>4</p>
<p id='salary'>5</p>
<p id='hdmf'>6</p>
<p id='otallowance'>7</p>
<p id='others'>8</p>
```

(I used `<p`>s here, since I didn't want to make a whole table structure, but the above will also work with `<td>`s. If the above ids refer to input boxes, you should use `document.getElementById(id).value` instead. Your question wasn't clear on this front.)

Comment: Thank you, this worked very well. I had to reassign my ids to the textboxes instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this (and therefore you don't need `$`).

You can concatenate a string without using jQuery like this:

```
"<td><input type=\"text\" autocomplete=\"off\" name=\"" + itemArray[i] + "\" id=\"" + itemArray[i] + "\"/></td>"
```

In addition, your variable in the `for` statement is capitalized (`I`), whereas the one you are using later on is not (`i`). Make sure they are the same case if you want your code to work.